# Passing Superclasses to C# Functions (With a Java overture)

Tags: c#, java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

It's been a while since I did anything with Java OOP, so I'm a bit rusty and wanted some clarification.

In Java, if I remember correctly, one could declare a superclass and instantiate a subclass; for example, `Superclass myObject = new Subclass()`.

One could then pass myObject into a function that accepted a Superclass parameter, and access any Superclass properties/methods using the reference.

Here's where things get foggy - if you want to access Subclass-specific methods/variables, can you do that directly with myObject (which was declared as a Superclass) or do you need to cast it first to a Subclass type?

If we roll this over to C# now, does the same logic apply? I'm running into some weird issues trying to duplicate this behavior. The specific use case I'm looking at is:

```
//These are just declarations for ease-of-reading
Superclass bar = new Subclass();
public static void doSomething(Superclass foo) {...}

//Logic
doSomething(bar);
bar.superOnly() //Should this work?
bar.subOnly() //Should this work?
bar.subOverrided() //Will this call the superclass or subclass version?
```

I'm looking up this stuff in tutorials as well, but most examples seem to be simple "Subclass myObject = new Subclass()" instances with trivial output. Nothing I've found so far covers the nebulous world of function parameters.

If anyone can help me out, or point me to a specific resource that covers function parameters and OO in C#, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Regarding parameters, I strongly suggest you read this article: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Here's where things get foggy - if you want to access Subclass-specific methods/variables, can you do that directly with myObject (which was declared as a Superclass) or do you need to cast it first to a Subclass type?

Yes, that's what polymorphism is for. Virtual methods of the base class that are overridden in the derived class will always be called, even if you call the method through a reference of the base type.

> If we roll this over to C# now, does the same logic apply?

Yes, the principle is the same

As for your example:

```
bar.superOnly() //Should this work?
```

Yes

```
bar.subOnly() //Should this work?
```

No, because the compiler wouldn't know about this method

```
bar.subOverrided() // Will this call the superclass or subclass version? => the subclass
```

Yes, thanks to polymorphism

Comment: What if you need to access methods specific to the subclass, not overridden methods from the base class?

Comment: @TheDramaLlama, then you need a reference of the subclass. The compiler has to know the method statically; since `subOnly` is only declared in `Subclass`, it can't be called on a variable of the super class

Comment: Gotcha. As per Woot4Moo's suggestion, I will probably end up altering the architecture of my app so I don't need to deal with this, as it seems a bit messy (and not extendable if I need to add 10 more subclasses, for example).

Comment: @TheDramaLlama, what are you trying to do exactly? I don't understand why you say it's not extendable; OOP is notoriously extendable... Perhaps you misunderstood something? Tell us more about your scenario, perhaps we can think of a good approach.

Comment: I'm dealing with multiple types of profiles (for example, GoogleProfile, FacebookProfile, etc). I want to pass them all to a single handler function, hence the Profile superclass. However, the way I'm approaching it now, I'll have to do manual checks and casting for every subclass of Profile that I create, which gets annoying if I need to add more Profile types later. I'm thinking of implementing this in a different way and moving the variation between Profiles to properties/functions in the Profile object instead of different Profile subclasses. Does that make sense for a rough explanation?

Comment: Actually that might not be the best implementation either. Maybe some sort of Dictionary would be better, since the only variation between the different Profile objects is the properties they contain. (They all contain some key properties such as Name, ID, etc, but some have additional ones like Email, URL, etc.)

Comment: Can't you implement the profile-specific behavior in their corresponding class? This way you could just declare an abstract method in the base class and implement it in the derived class.

Comment: That's a rat's nest that I'd rather not dive into just yet, as the conditional behavior that these variations affect are actual UI changes (i.e., display these UI elements and do UI logic if it's a Google profile, display these different UI elements for a Facebook profile, filling out different fields with different unique profile variables, etc). I'd like to avoid passing UI elements deeper into my app if at all possible, and certainly don't want to pass my form itself to other classes to modify. Do you have any recommendations as to how to handle this situation?

Comment: PropertyBag style implementation with a Dictionary is the way I went on something similar. Inheritance or an Interface might work for some simple behaviours of "Profile", but is near usless for discrete properties of such disparate ones

Answer (score 3):

Two ways to get the functionality you desire.

1)  Cast the object to the subclass
2)  Instantiate the object as the subclass from the beginning.

For number one if I have a `Collection` that has no idea about what an `ArrayList` does it is impossible to invoke the methods of `ArrayList`.

```
Collection collection = new ArrayList();
```

Example for number two:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
```

The above gives me access to everything that is public (shared from the parent class/interface) and everything that is declared within the `ArrayList`

Comment: I have to use the first option, since I'm trying to pass multiple types of objects into a single function. Are you saying the only way I can access subclass-specific properties after passing in "Superclass myClass" is to cast it inside my function using "(Subclass)myClass"?

Comment: @thedramallama Yes.  You need to check the type of the object, or seriously reconsider the architecture of your program.

Comment: Gotcha. This is being used in a messy interim debug version due to timeframe limitations; eventually this will all be made much more elegant. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call a method that is **only declared on the subclass**, you must cast your variable to the subclass or start with a variable of the subclass type.

If you want to call a method that is **overridden on the subclass**, you can call it through the superclass variable, and the subclass's version will be called.

Answer (score 2):

In both C# and Java, the rules are pretty consistent.

You **declare** a variable with a particular type which dictates the interface available for you to use.  The declared type is the type name before the variable.  Only methods defined as part of the declared type are available to use (without casting).

In contrast, the **definition** can be the declared type or any subclass or implementation of the declared type.  The definition doesn't alter the interface available to you through that variable, it defines the implementation of that variable.  The definition of an object variable is the value assigned to it (right-hand side), usually with `new`.

The declared type of a variable can only be changed by casting to some other type, which may or may not succeed (and the compiler won't necessarily know whether your cast is valid).

Comment: THANK YOU! This just brought everything rushing back to me. This is what happens when you spend too much time with loosely-typed Python in academia and get spoiled. :)